# In Flutter, how do I create custom buttons like the one in the provided image?

Tags: flutter, button

[image: A self made image of two buttons. One is circular and the other is rectangular. The the right end of the rectangular button wraps around the circular button]

How would I create something like this in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be to use a container and then add a gesture dectector   to it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CircularButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Container(
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue, shape: BoxShape.circle),
        child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The strange shape on the other hand could be achieved in two ways. You could create a single container with two shapes where one clips another. This is the `most straightforward` path in my mind but the right way would be to override a render method and then write custom coordinates.

This is gonna get you like 70% of the way.

```
class ButtonWithCurve extends CustomPainter{
  
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    
    

  // Square
  
  Paint paint_stroke_1 = Paint()
      ..color = const Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 150, 243)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = size.width*0.00
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt
      ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.miter;
     
         
    Path path_1 = Path();
    path_1.moveTo(0,0);
    path_1.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.4431818,0,size.width*0.5909091,0);
    path_1.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.6138636,size.height*0.7354167,size.width*0.9990909,size.height*1.0016667);
    path_1.lineTo(0,size.height*1.0033333);
    path_1.lineTo(0,0);
    path_1.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path_1, paint_stroke_1);
  
    
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could you finish the rest 30% of the way there and give me the coordinates to clip the two buttons together so it looks like the picture above. Thanks again

Comment: No I will not do it for you.